# Can't get the data from map

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Okay I should be dumb, the first console log gives me data but when I put it through map it shows undefined. I really made some digging but stuck at this stage.

```js
import React from 'react'

const Users = ({ users } : { users:any }) => {
  return (
    <div>
        { console.log(users) }


      {users.map(({user} : {user:any},{i} : {i:any}) => (
        <div className="card">
            {console.log("test: " + user)}
          <div className="card-body">
            <h5 className="card-title">{user.name}</h5>
            <h6 className="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{user.name}</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
};

export default Users
```

Comment: TypeScript should be able to infer the types because you have explicitly set them in the parameters. So you should remove all the type annotations in the `.map` part. (also because `{i}` and `{user}` is destructuring, which is not what you want)

Comment: why are you putting a console log inside the return? Also, remember to tag your question with the language you're using. Is this typescript?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans yes, and I didn't know how to check my value. Any ideas to improve it?

Comment: just put your console log _before_ the return. You're not using an arrow function for anything that needs an arrow function anyway (you're not referencing `this` anywhere) so just make it a normal function, since you already have a block scope and explicit return statement.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans no but I had to check the value of user inside of the map since it was undefined, it was only for testing purpose so that I could find where did I wrong and found but could not resolve the issue :D so I ask here

Comment: That's not what I'm talking about. You have a console.log _outside_ your map, but _inside_ your return. So in the future, put _that_ kind of code above the return, don't make it part of the templating operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `users` is an array of user objects, try this:

```
import React from 'react'

const Users = ({ users } : { users:any }) => {
  return (
    <div>
        { console.log(users) }


      {users.map((user : any, i : any) => (
        <div className="card">
            {console.log("test: " + user)}
          <div className="card-body">
            <h5 className="card-title">{user.name}</h5>
            <h6 className="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{user.name}</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
};

export default Users
```

Comment: can you please explain? I am a beginner. Appreciate the help by the way!

Comment: The bit that I changed is the `map({ user }: { user: any})` when you put a variable in curly brackets it's called destructuring. So you're saying take the key "user" from the first parameter and assign it to the variable "user", but because you're mapping over an array of objects, you don't need to destructure

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript can infer the types because you have explicitly set them:

```
import React from 'react'

const Users = ({ users } : { users:any }) => {
  return (
    <div>
        { console.log(users) }


      {users.map((user, i) => (
        <div className="card">
            {console.log("test: " + user)}
          <div className="card-body">
            <h5 className="card-title">{user.name}</h5>
            <h6 className="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{user.name}</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
};

export default Users
```